# torsion and curvature of a arc length paramtric curve that lies on a sphere

Tags: geometry, curves

let's say $\beta$:$I$->1$E^{3}$ is a arc length paramertic curve that lies on the unit sphere. Let's say that $k$ isn't zero.
If $j$:$I$->$R$:$j(s)$=det[$\beta(s)$ $\beta'(s)$ $\beta''(s)$] = $\beta''(s)$$(\beta(s)$ x $\beta'(s)$)
then $k(s)=\sqrt(1+j^{2}(s))$ and $\tau$=$j'(s)$/(1+$j^{2}(s)$)

I started with k=$||T'(s)||$=$||\beta''(s)||$=$||(\beta(s)$ x $\beta'(s))j(s)||$
But i'm stuck with the crossproduct. Can someone help me further?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Curvature of a curve lying on a sphere?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676011/curvature-of-a-curve-lying-on-a-sphere)